# SQL - Aggregate query using SUM function - won't aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help.

I want my code to sum the listed [Values] for each [CTN]. I believe the code is only applying the SUM aggregate function to [Values] which are the same for each [CTN] and so there is more than 1 [CTN].

Example table (i can't post images) bold=row number/ 2 columns/ used '.' to space columns so they line up:

- [CTN].....................[Value]
- **1** 000A-434D-BC .  5864.04
- **2** 000A-434D-BC .  5102.97
- **3** 0031-4C10-84 .. 12247.128
- **4** 0031-4C10-84 .. 5864.04

I expect to see:

- [CTN].....................[Value]
- **1** 000A-434D-BC .  10965.01
- **2** 0031-4C10-84 .. 18087.168

My code:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT y.CTN
,SUM(y.[Value]) AS 'Total'
FROM(
  SELECT CarrierTrackingNumber AS 'CTN'
    ,SalesOrderDetailID AS 'Orders'
    ,[Value] = UnitPrice*OrderQty
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE CarrierTrackingNumber IS NOT NULL
) AS y
GROUP BY CTN, Value
HAVING Value > 4000
ORDER BY CTN
```

Comment: remove the Value from group by

Comment: Explanation: `GROUP BY CTN, Value` means: "give me one result line per CTN and Value". But you want one result line per CTN only.

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't use single quotes ' for aliases. In standard SQL these are reserved for string literals. Use double quotes " for aliases instead (if you want to quote them at all).

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, i picked it up as a habit from examples and trying to avoid misinterpretation of KEYWORD/FUNCTION names. In future i will either use [name] or name. :)

Comment: Whoever down-voted this question; please state your reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `value` from the `group by` and fix the `having` clause.  Also, the subquery is unnecessary:

```
SELECT CarrierTrackingNumber, SUM(UnitPrice*OrderQty) AS Total
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE CarrierTrackingNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CarrierTrackingNumber
HAVING Total > 4000
ORDER BY CarrierTrackingNumber;
```

**RESPONSE/CONCLUSION:**

***My code now (working with an addition)*** the subquery existed because i misinterpreted an error i thought that it was not possible to sum over a computed column:

```
SELECT CarrierTrackingNumber
    ,COUNT(CarrierTrackingNumber) AS 'Count'
    ,SUM(UnitPrice*OrderQty) AS 'Total'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE CarrierTrackingNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CarrierTrackingNumber
ORDER BY CarrierTrackingNumber ASC
```

Comment: The answer was to remove [value] from the GROUP BY clause. "duh"